# How to fill a Pandas data frame based on listed index

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame:

```
     sample1  sample2  sample3
foo       20       10       11
bar       17       13       55
```

It is created with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""sample1,sample2,sample3
foo,20,10,11
bar,17,13,55"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp))
```

What I want to do is given a list

```
complete_ids = ["foo","bar","cix","tux"]
```

I would like to fill the above data frame resulting this:

```
     sample1  sample2  sample3
foo       20       10       11
bar       17       13       55
cix       0         0       0
tux       0         0       0
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an empty dataframe with the desired index and join:

```
full_index = pd.DataFrame(index=complete_ids)
full_index.join(df).fillna(0)
Out[8]: 
     sample1  sample2  sample3
foo       20       10       11
bar       17       13       55
cix        0        0        0
tux        0        0        0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) and [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) for this:

```
In [27]:
complete_ids = ["foo","bar","cix","tux"]
df.reindex(complete_ids).fillna(0)

Out[27]:
     sample1  sample2  sample3
foo       20       10       11
bar       17       13       55
cix        0        0        0
tux        0        0        0
```